# Are all polynomial expressions an algebraic expression.

Tags: linear-algebra

I mean to ask that,  real numbers can be written  in the form of constant  polynomials like, 4x^0, 2x^0 etc. If all polynomial expressions  are algebraic  expressions  then 
4x^0 = 4x^0  should be a polynomial  equation  implying  that it is an algebraic  equation  too. 
But it does not contain  any variable.  After simplification  it is 4 = 4.  4 is a real number  so this equation can be called an arithmetic  equation  also. 
again 4 -- 4 = 0  is a zero polynomial  equation  because  0=0 is an  equation  consisting two polynomial  expressions  0 and 0 separated by an equivalence.  This is really confusing please help and also state  the difference  between  algebraic  equation  and polynomial equation.
whether  all polynomial  equations are algebraic  equation or not.

Comment: Your title is not coherent.

Answer (score 0):

*Algebraic equation* and *polynomial equation* are synonyms. They are both asking for the roots of a polynomial.

But *algebraic expression* has a wider sense than *polynomial expression* (rarely used) in that it allows divisions and rational exponents. (If you allow just division, you get a *rational expression*.)

By decreasing generality, an algebraic expression is also a rational expression, which is also a polynomial expression, which is also an arithmetic expression.