# Is the number $7$ a polynomial expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I mean to ask  that $7$ is an arithmetic  expression  but it can also  be  written  as $7x^0$.  which is a constant polynomial  expression.  Every polynomial  expression  is an algebraic  expression  so with  this logic is $7$ an algebraic  expression  or an arithmetic  expression.  Further $7=5+2$, is it an arithmetic  equation  or algebraic  equation  because  it can also be written  in  $7x^0 = 5x^0 + 2x^0$ form.
please help.  Thank you.

Comment: *Entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem*

Comment: @A.Γ. Seems interesting. Can't understand Latin. Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @hellotinfish "Do not produce multiple notions without necessity". The words being attributed to [William of Ockham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) who stated the principle that the simplest possible explanation should be considered first.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464155/are-all-polynomial-expressions-an-algebraic-expression)

Answer (score 5):

There is great overlap. You could ask a similar question about whether $7$ is a natural number or a real number. The answer is that it's both, kind of like how [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SREKd.jpg) can be both a rabbit and a duck.
A different kind of overlap between notions is the way a cat is both a mammal and an animal, as said in a deleted comment above.

Specifically, seeing $7$ as both a number and as a polynomial is somewhere in-between the two swaps outlined above, while seeing $7$ as both a natural number and as a real number is definitely of the cat-animal-mammal variety.

Being able to swap interpretations on the fly (but being conscious about it) is something that is important to any good mathematician, and many elegant proofs come from interpreting one thing as something else.

Comment: +1 Nice. Perhaps make clear that there are at least two different kinds of swaps. One is in terms of subsets (natural number versus real number). Another is viewpoint (rabbit versus duck, or Cartesian plane versus vector space). In elementary school being able to see a fraction as a way to cut up a pizza but also as a number on the number line is important and subtle.

Comment: @EthanBolker I never really liked the "cutting pizza / cake" interpretation of fractions. It's fine for addition, but you get into trouble when you try to define multiplication (how do you make sense of what you get when you multiply one piece of pizza with another?) At any rate, you're right, I could be clearer that the two swaps are different.

Comment: I agree that pizza cutting is a bad route to rational number arithmetic. But it's a reasonable place to start on fractions with (say) second graders. Then you have to manage the transition. It helps if the teacher (in later grades) knows that there is a transition to be made, even if s/he doesn't make that explicit to the kids right away. But now we're wandering off topic for this question and answer.

Comment: it is not about different  meanings  or perspective .  it is about fundamental  difference  between algebra  and arithmetic.

Comment: @PriyanshuKumar And what I'm saying is that there is no fundamental difference. They are two sides of the same coin (different but fundamentally connected) and realising what that means is an important step on the road  to mathematical enlightenment.