# 4 is a mathematical expression . It has one term so it is a monomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am asking  if 4 is a mathematical  expression  and  it is a monomial.  Monomials are polynomials with single term. 
so 4 is a polynomial  expression .  which is a constant  polynomial  expression  because it can be written  in this form 4x^0. 
all polynomial  expressions  are algebraic  expressions . 
so 4 is an algebraic  expression  also.
But 4 is a numerical  expression  rather than an algebraic  expression  because there must have a variable  to be called an algebraic  expression.  Its a paradox please solve. 
one more question  what algebraic  expressions with  one  term is called if it is not a polynomial  eg.  root (x).

Comment: This is essentially the same question you asked here, so the answer is essentially the same. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464444/is-the-number-7-a-polynomial-expression

Comment: Why are the answers to your previous similar questions insufficient?

Comment: this question  is  different  please have a look again and earlier question  was irrelevantly answered.

Comment: it was insufficient  because  I  didn't  get satisfaction.